# Why are color settings not saved when exporting to a new file?

Tags: qgis, color, vector-grid

I extracted with QGIS a municipality from a state map, then divided it with a grid. I don't want the borders of the grid features to be seen so I changed the color of the map and the color of the borders to be the same, then I saved it as a new file (not a new project). Does anyone know why when I open it again it does not save the changes? (the divisions of the grid are visible and the color settings I saved are gone).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

QGIS does not store the style in the layer data itself because it handles different formats so that would be hard.  Styles are stored in the project file or in a qml file.

To export the QML file. Open the Layer Properties and select the Save Properties button.

**Tip:** If you name the qml file the same as the vector file it will auto style when you open it.  `myshape.shp` and `myshape.qml`